# Reading HBase WAL file with Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, wal

I need to read Hbase WAL in my code. 
I found out the class https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/wal/HLogPrettyPrinter.html. However it doesn't look like class for external use. Does someone have experience of using it?
Or are there another correct way of reading HBase WAL programatically?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: may I know the use case, you are trying to achieve by reading WAL files? Because WAL files are stored in HDFS, and when on bulk, it can really affect your use case

Comment: @Ramzy, I need it because in my program I need to be able to recieve all updates coming to database. The only way I see is to read WAL.

Comment: @miuser were you able to do this? Even I am trying to track updates in HBase using WAL with no luck